# Or-equals on constant as reduction operation (ex. value |= 1 ) thread-safe?

Tags: thread-safety, opencl

Let's say that I have a variable x.

```
x = 0
```

I then spawn some number of threads, and each of them may or may not run the following expression WITHOUT the use of atomics.

```
x |= 1
```

After all threads have joined with my main thread, the main thread branches on the value.

```
if(x) { ... } else { ... }
```

Is it possible for there to be a race condition in this situation? My thoughts say no, because it doesn't seem to matter whether or not a thread is interrupted by another thread between reading and writing 'x' (in both cases, either 'x == 1', or 'x == 1'). That said, I want to make sure I'm not missing something stupid obvious or ridiculously subtle.

Also, if you happen to provide an answer to the contrary, please provide an instruction-by-instruction example!

**Context:**
I'm trying to, in OpenCL, have my threads indicate the presence or absence of a feature among *any* of their work-items. If any of the threads indicate the presence of the feature, my host ought to be able to branch on the result. I'm thinking of using the above method. If you guys have a better suggestion, that works too!

**Detail:**
I'm trying to add early-exit to my OpenCL radix-sort implementation, to skip radix passes if the data is banded (i.e. 'x' above would be x[RADIX] and I'd have all work groups, right after partial reduction of the data, indicate presence or absence of elements in the RADIX bins via 'x').

Answer (score 0):

It may work within a work-group. You will need to insert a barrier before testing x. I'm not sure it will be faster than using atomic increments.

It will not work across several work-groups.  Imagine you have 1000 work-groups to run on 20 cores.  Typically, only a small number of work-groups can be resident on a single core, for example 4, meaning only 80 work-groups can be in flight inside the GPU at a given time.  Once a work-group is done executing, it is retired, and another one is started. Halting a kernel in the middle of execution to wait for all 1000 work-groups to reach the same point is impossible.

Comment: Could you explain _why_ it _wouldn't_ work across multiple work groups, while it would work within a work-group? I would have less disbelief if it worked within a warp/wavefront and not across multiple work-groups, but in any case, I need to have an explicit example of it _not working_ if it won't work. No hand waving.